# Configuring app()->db;

Tags: php, yii

I have this function:

```
function getCompensation($id)
{
    $dbh = app()->db;
    try {
        $amount = $dbh->createCommand()
        ->select('data')
        ->from('compensation_table')
        ->where('id = :id', array(':id'=>$id))
        ->queryRow();
    }catch (Exception e) 
        $e->getMessage();
    {
     return $amount;
}
```

However it seems that app()->db; doesn't behave as it should, because I am not getting any data. I use the same method in another project, but I am not sure how it was configured. I would like to connect to the same database. Can we configure it inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be you must specify  $amount = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()

```
function getCompensation($id)
{

    try {
        $amount = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('data')
        ->from('compensation_table')
        ->where('id = :id', array(':id' =>$id))
        ->queryRow();
    }catch (Exception e) 
        $e->getMessage();
    {
     return $amount;
}
```

and if you have a column 'data'

you can access the column with eg:

```
 echo $amount->data;
```

this is sample of the db section in component in

```
proteteced/config/main.php
```

.

```
.....
return array(


    ....

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
       ......

      'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_databasename',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'my_username',
        'password' => 'my_pwd',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
      ),
```

Comment: how do you specify which database app()->db connects to?

Comment: Normally the db connection is  specified in protected/config/main.php  component -> db .... you need a sample?